# Appgyver Steroids Phonegap Add Android Platform

Tags: cordova, build, phonegap-build, cordova-3, steroids

I am new in Appgyver Steroids Phonegap. As per their documentation i have added android platform by using cordova cli commands [here](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids_npm/using-cordova-cli/). My question is that

1. Should every time i have to connect steroids server by using
   "steroids connect" command ?
2. Or i can add added android platform
   into my eclipse project and from their i can run project. But here i
   am not getting full access to steroids js files and native effects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova CLI build commands take care of copying over the `www/` folder to the native project, so you don't have to use `$ steroids connect` if you are running your project via Eclipse. However, the Steroids native UI features are currently only available inside the Steroids runtime, so Eclipse use is limited pretty much to e.g. plugin development and debugging.

For regular Steroids.js development, you should download the AppGyver Scanner app from Google Play and use that with `$ steroids connect` to develop your project.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but... I'm using windows 8.1 and have everything setup for steroids.js development. I used eclipse, but as suggested by developers, it is buggy and no stable. So, to deploy the app I could use steroids connect, but where should I develop my app? Directly the www folder, using notepad++?

Comment: Open your Steroids or Supersonic project folder in your favourite editor (be it Notepad++ or something else), launch `steroids connect` and scan the QR code. Then watch the application starting on your device :)